# How can we get a warning when the request per second pass a certain limit. (Quotas of Cognito AWS)

Tags: amazon-cognito

Our web application is using UserAuthentication Cognito, there is a problem that arises when a lot of users authenticate in 1 second. We want to limit the Quotas if possible and have a warning when it exceeds a certain amount to prevent system overloading. We haven't found a solution to this problem yet.

Can you help us solve this problem? Maybe with some example code or a return response containing content of message and place of error log whenever it breaks the limit.

Comment: `TooManyRequestsException` - This exception is thrown when the user has made too many requests for a given operation.

Comment: Thanks. Can i control numbers of request and show alert popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using cloudwatch alarms to send notifications when certain quotas are being exceeded. This notification can be directly sent to your app to perform further actions.

If your app cannot recieve notifications, you can use the alarm to trigger a lamdba which updates a database. You can then create a pre authentication lambda trigger that will query this database before logging user in.

Here's the documentation for cognito cloudwatch alarms: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/tracking-quotas-and-usage-in-cloud-watch-and-service-quotas.html